# Authorization in django-websocket-redis

Tags: python, django, websocket, authorization

I'm using Django v. 1.7.6, django rest framework and [django-websocket-redis](https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I want to send message across websocket. 
At first, I tried sending websocket broadcast messages as described in this [manual](https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#subscribe-to-broadcast-notifications).

Client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import websocket
import thread
import time
import requests

def on_message(ws, message):
    print message

def on_error(ws, error):
    print error

def on_close(ws):
    print "### closed ###"

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print "thread terminating..."
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost/ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast&echo",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    # ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Server code:

```
msg = RedisMessage("some message")
RedisPublisher(facility='foobar', broadcast=True).publish_message(msg)
```

It's work.
Then I tried sending websocket message to authorize user as described in manual.

On the server side, I replace one string:

```
msg = RedisMessage("some msg")
RedisPublisher(facility='foobar', users=[SELF]).publish_message(msg)
```

But I don't know what I should do on the client side.

I thought it necessary to send cookies with key 'csrftoken'. I can do it:

```
r = requests.get("http://localhost/api/authlogin/") 
token_value = r.cookies['csrftoken']
cookie = "csrftoken = " + token_value
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost/ws/foobar?subscribe-user",
                          on_message = on_message,
                          on_error = on_error,
                          on_close = on_close,
                          cookie = cookie)
```

But it doesn't work. Could you help me please?

**Added:**
I found out, that I should send "sessionid" to cookies during connection to websocket. I can get sessionid like this:

```
import requests
payload = dict()
payload['password'] = "12345"
payload['username'] = "admin"
req = requests.post("http://localhost/api/auth-token/", data=payload)   
session_id = req.cookies['sessionid']
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
# ... some urls
url(r'^api/auth-token/?', views.ObtainAuthToken.as_view(), name="auth-token")]
```

In views.py:

```
class ObtainAuthToken(views.APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = (utils.NoAuth,)
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)

def post(self, request):
    """
    Provide auth token by username and password
    ---
    type:
        - name: token

    request_serializer: rest_framework.authtoken.serializers.AuthTokenSerializer
    responseMessages:
        - code: 400
          message: Bad request
    """
    serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

    user_logged_in.send(sender=self.__class__, request=request, user=user)
    session_key = request.session._get_or_create_session_key()
    print ("views.py::session_key = ", session_key)

    return Response({'token': token.key})
```

Some row created in DB table named django_session, when I logged in as I wrote above.
Some row created in DB table named django_session, when I logged in using browser. It using other URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/auth/?', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),]
```

Websockets working successfully if I using second sessionid (by hardcode), but doesn't work with first sessionid.

Comment: django websocket redis doesn't support this feature, proof link: [github](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis/issues/164)